# Unbind not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm having an issue with my scroll event unbinding in IE8. It works fine in every other browser. I'm using jQuery 1.7.0. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 200)
            {
                jQuery('#graph3').attr("src","/images/stories/Graph-3.gif");
                setTimeout(4000);
                jQuery(window).unbind("scroll");
            }

        });

    $.noConflict();
    </script>
```

Comment: Remove the `setTimeout` (which causes an error and stopping of execution in IE) and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetTimeout can't be call with one parameter : `setTimeout(4000);`

Do this instead :

```
 setTimeout(function(){jQuery(window).unbind("scroll");
}, 4000);
```